# Is it possible to detect what operating system a user is coming from using PHP? (mac or windows)

Tags: php

Let's say for example I wanted to echo "You are using Windows!" or "You are using Macintosh!", depending on the users OS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/get_browser) function that's built into PHP.

```
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "Platform: " . $browser["platform"] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 14):

By analyzing `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` it's possible to tell what **system** (and **browser**) the user is *claiming* to use.

It's easily spoofable, though.

Comment: +1 for easily spoofable and for explaining how to retrieve the user agent string.

Answer (score 6):

You can look at the [user agent string](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), which often includes information about the OS.

Note, however, that there are operating systems other than Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 1):

http://phpcode.mypapit.net/detect-ip-location-operating-system-and-browser-using-php-detector-library/46/

The library is handy for for creating web application which serve content depending on users location and type of operating system/browser that he use or for creating web application that collect web surfers statistical data.

code example:

```
  require('detector.php');
  $dip = &new Detector($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);

  echo "$dip->town";

  echo "$dip->state, $dip->ccode,$dip->town, ($dip->ipaddress) ";

  echo "using : $dip->browser $dip->browser_version on $dip->os $dip->os_version";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

You want to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` which holds information about the user's operating system and browser.

You can use [this resource](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) to look up user agent strings (which are held in that variable).

However, it is possible for browsers to spoof this information so you can't assume that this is reliable.